Error in Springer template on table with adjustbox
I am getting the following errors from the code given below:
Missing \endgroup inserted.
LaTeX Error: \begin{threeparttable} on input line 66 ended by \end{tabular}.
 LaTeX Error: \begin{center} on input line 122 ended by \end{adjustbox}. 
Missing } inserted.
LaTeX Error: \begin{tableorg} on input line 122 ended by \end{threeparttable}.
LaTeX Error: \begin{table} on input line 122 ended by \end{center}.
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
LaTeX Error: \begin{landscape} on input line 121 ended by \end{tableorg}.
LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{table}.
Extra \endgroup
LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{landscape}.

\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{nicefrac, xfrac}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
%\usepackage{tabularx, tabulary, tabu, longtable}
%\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm} %Table Border Thickness
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1} %Cell Height scaling
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%
%\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 
%\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
%\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
%\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%
%\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%
%\usepackage{tabularx, tabulary, tabu, longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{longtable,lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

%\usepackage{xltabular} % For 'xltabular' env. Loads the 'tabularx'
                       % and 'longtable' packages automatically
%\usepackage{ragged2e}  % For '\RaggedRight' macro
%\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
%\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=#1\hsize}X}

\raggedbottom
%%\unnumbered% uncomment this for unnumbered level heads

\begin{document}



\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Detailed comparison of features of the previously reported  fractional-order analog filters}\label{table1}%

\begin{adjustbox}{width=\columnwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline

\multirow{2}{*}{Ref.} & \multirow{2}{*}{ABB used} & \multirow{2}{*}{Filter realization} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Number of elements}& \multirow{2}{*}{Topology} & \multirow{2}{*}{Technique used} & \multirow{2}{*}{Order of filter} & \multirow{2}{*}{Electronic controllability} & \multirow{2}{*}{Type of control} & \multirow{2}{*}{Operating mode} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Performance parameters for filter analysis} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Verification} & \multirow{2}{*}{Sensitivity analysis} &\multirow{2}{*}{Stability analysis}& \multirow{2}{*}{Compared with IOF} & \multirow{2}{*}{Supply voltage} & \multirow{2}{*}{Power Consumption}  \\
\cmidrule{4-7}
\cmidrule{14-18}

&&&ABBs&R&C&FOE&&&&&&&$\omega_{max/min}$/$\omega_{osc}$&$\omega_{3dB}$/$\omega_{o}$&$\omega_{rp}$&$Q$-factor&Simulation/Experiment&&&&&\\
 \hline

\cite{r1}&NA& FOLPF, FOHPF, FOBPF and FOAPF based on passive FO-RC circuit& 0&1,3&0&1& FOC& RC network & $\alpha$ & No& - & VM& Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes/Yes & No & No &Yes&NA&NA \\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}

Please, can you help me?

It is usually a bad idea to scale things which contain text, like tables. Either change the layout of the table or choose a suitable font size instead.

Your column headers are far too wide.  How would you create this table by hand?  You may need to split it into two (or three) separate tables.  (Also, I don't have sn-jnl.cls, so I can't reproduce your error.)
